Steven Work's points
Steven Work, a new user without rep, had some comments which at his current privilege he cannot make. So he made edits to my answer. I've split his additions into material suitable for main and the rest suitable for here. Following is what would belong here. Followed by my responses.

[@Rushi, sorry to use this method to communicate but I do not have the 50 points needed to comment
... main part snipped — it's on the main answer
I have received some neg. votes for suggestions similar to your answer here, touching on these themes, and so have been blocked from answering, as well as losing my ability to comment... I can not help but wonder if my answers have not 'rubbed' some people or mods the wrong way.
As a result of the blocking, I have more than one Answer pending my unBlocking that gives examples of personal experiences where others witnessed that seems to only make sense through us shifting across multiworlds. I hope to be unBlocked so they may be added - while those Questions are still active and fresh in people's thoughts.
Of course, I also expect those Answers to be crushed and the blocking to return .. sad. I was so excited to have found this site because since I retired, I missed the debates of these type of questions between co-workers in my 12+ ears of basic medical research career, and my 6+ years working in an engineering research and manufacturing company.
Again, sorry to use this method to respond. ]

As to the point of your answers being blocked, we can try to hammer them into acceptable shape. Can you use this chat?

Judging by the only visible answer currently on their account, I'd say we're a long, long way from anything that wouldn't be downvoted into oblivion on this site. Far too much preaching and fear-mongering with questionable presentations of facts. They mention Aquinas and Descartes, but they also mention Satan a bunch of times. This is a site where anyone is welcome, but only if you can meet quality standards, and that isn't for everyone. It's easier to direct someone elsewhere, where they may fit in better, rather than trying to get their content to a point where it would fit here.

@Steven Work -- Responding to points in your deleted answer:  1) as others have pointed out, this is not a discussion site.  Your desire for thoughtful dialog on the interface between theology and philosophy is only meetable here in chat discussions.  It can be somewhat supported by questions and answers, but the main point of our questions and answers is to improve understanding of what philosophy/philosophers think, not DO philosophy ourselves.  The understanding of other thinkers and ideas that this site facilitates, HELPS with doing philosophy yourself, but that is an indirect benefit.


Citations of personal experience are not inappropriate here, see https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/  BUT -- your personal experiences do not, I fear, show as much as you think they do about the ontology of our universe.  The "one walker gets a companion" example you cited, does not involve any prayer, and the only anomaly you cite if one takes a multiverse perspective is that you and your companion's memories seem to be ported in from some other universe.  Neither a quantum affected multiverse, nor prayer caused movement between nearby ones, is evident.



continued.  It is important in empiricism to adopt Popperian search for falsifications, not a search for CONfirmations.  This is because we humans are strongly inclined to believe what we want to believe, and every worldview has at least a few confirming supports.  Search for falsifications helps to sort between worldviews far better than search for these sorts of weak "confirmations".



the missing object, then refound, once more is not what your quantum multiverse plus prayer jumps would predict.  If you with your memories jumped to another multiverse with no dropped object, then jumped to a different one where it was dropped again, WITH NO INTENTIONS NOR PRAYER, what you are describing is multiple random "glitches in the matrix" -- IE the unreality/instability of our world, NOT a multiverse, nor prayer influence upon one's location in it.  Given all our experience with difficulty finding things due to mundane reasons, this example seems trivial as well.



If you are an experimental engineer, you know how sensors and electronics can be affected by EM environments.  And the sun as an EM source is not entirely blocked in all frequencies by walls and a bag that block visual light.  Why are you surprised that a sensor picks up some additional signal in the sun's direction?  And why do you leap to a multiverse and prayer model, when neither seem to be relevant at all to what you describe?  None of these three personal experiences are what one would predict to happen if you model is true about our universe.


I understand the direction of thinking to prevent forum style discussions on this highly rated (by Google) knowledge site. I saw the same dynamic in the Space Exploration meta. People think of themselves as a source of truth (for Google searches). And they imagine it clean, correct, strict to the point and most importantly unambiguous.
But people naturally want to discuss, especially on issues they don't agree with.
So the solution will always be some form of hybrid.

Stack exchange is explicitly designed as an attempt to create a crowdsourced "source of truth", which is why people tend to hammer on it being a question and answer site rather than a discussion site, and why comments are explicitly supposed to be used to help clarify questions and answers rather than to discuss them. The form of "discussion"  recommended here is to let the community express agreement or disagreement by voting, or by posting alternative answers. Not every question is well suited to this mode, and not all users are comfortable with it. Sometimes the question belongs elsewhere.

(The irony that meta has to be an exception to that is not lost on anyone. Arguably meta should be a structured chat rather than a stack, but they used the tool they happened to have on hand.)

@keshlam - The problem is people, as usual. This is not a tight-knit bunch of respected scholars. And this uneven intellectual footprint creates disagreements and even conflicts.

Even if we were a tight-knit bunch of intellectual scholars, there is more than enough evidence that that does not prevent disagreement and conflict. All we can do is try to limit how often it arises, and manage it when it does, hopefully maintaining an environment where we can respectfully disagree. That isn't a science; it's social engineering, which means it's always going to be somewhat ad-hoc and based on practical considerations more than theoretical ones.

Then on top of that, more specifically for philosophy, you have an adolescent problem when people lose their roots (parents) and run wild with ideas of physicalism (materialism) that were traditionally considered vulgar by almost all great minds.

"Almost all great minds" predated the present. Knowing the history is great, but many historical views have been proven wrong, or failing that are now disfavored. "Vulgarity"does not demonstrate incorrectness. And people's parents may also have been physicalists. You are stating your own bias, which you are entitled to but which you have to accept others will disagree with. As I have said elsewhere, please accept and respect that others have thought as deeply about these questions as you have, even if they do not come to the same conclusions. If that bothers you, find better arguments.

My standard Dean Inge quote, via John Brunner's  book Shockwave Rider: "There are two kinds of fool. One says 'this is old and therefore good.' the other says 'this is new and therefore better'."

"but many historical views have been proven wrong" - I sincerely confident that you could have this kind of opinion if you grew up in US and learned social studies instead of History as a science.

I am not sure what you're saying. In my school there was not a distinction between the two. Your mileage will vary.

But we seem to be drifting very far off topic... My apologies to all for that.

And frankly, I find most folks on this stack reasonably respectable and reasonably respectful. And you aren't going to get much more order than this on an open board.
